# How write new NCONC function?

Tags: common-lisp

How the function receive two parameters of lists, making first lists of last pointer to second lists. The function returns one list, it's a pointer to first lists.
Below is the code I have written:

```
(defun  my-new-nconc (x y)
    (if (null x)
        y
        (setf (cdddr x) y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RPLACD`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rplaca.htm) to set the cdr of the last cons in `X` to `Y`.

```
(defun my-new-nconc (x y)
  (if x
      (progn (rplacd (last x) y)
             x)
      y))

(defparameter *foo* (list 1 2 3))
(defparameter *bar* (list 4 5 6))
(my-new-nconc *foo* *bar*)

*foo*
;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: It is more common to see `setf` of `cdr` instead of `rplacd`, but nothing wrong with either.

Comment: Insert mandatory "don't modify literal data" here. (Yes, I know it's just an example, but perhaps that makes it even more important for the users who look for a question like this...)

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is basically to concatenate two lists:

```
(defun concatenate-lists (x y)
   "this function check that x and y are lists and concatenates them"
    (when (and (listp x) (listp y))
      (concatenate 'list x y)))
```

for example:

```
(concatenate-lists '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
```

if one of them is not a list the result will be *NIL*